# .haccess link rewrite, new link missing php Get variables

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, variables, get

In my website I a trying to change my link from this:

```
example.com/news/foobar.php?id=21&artName=Hello-World
```

to look like this:

```
example.com/news/foobar/21/Hello-World
```

in my .htaccess file I have the following code:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.htaccess">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*)$ ^news/foobar.php?id=$1&artName=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

My link to the article looks like this:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/news/foobar/'.$row['id'].'/'.$row['linkAddress'].'" class="post-title">'.$row['aName'].'</a>
```

Where it collects the id and name from the variable, whenever I click on that article link my website loads but the php Get variables are missing so the page does not display the article information (meaning article id and name are missing so page does not collect the information). I have tried rewriting the code in my .htaccess but this is the only one I found that did not end in a 404 error when I click the article. I have been stuck for some time, please let me know what I can do to fix this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ReWriteRule**

The structure of a rewrite rule is typically:

```
ReWriteCond SOME_CONDITION
ReWriteRule REGEX_FOR_INPUT_STRING OUTPUT_STRING [FLAGS]
```

In your case we don't strictly need a condition, so we can skip to the re-write rule:

```
RewriteRule ^news/foobar/(\d+)/([\w-]+)/?$ news/foobar.php?id=$1&artName=$2 [NC,L,NE]
```

**Explanation**

```
// Matching Regex:

^news/foobar/(\d+)/([\w-]+)/?$
^                               : Matches the start of the string
 news/foobar/                   : Matches the first two "directories" in the URL
             (\d+)              : Capture group 1 to get the id
                  /             : Matches a slash between id and artName
                   ([\w-]+)     : Capture group 2 to capture artName
                           /?   : Matches an optional closing /
                             $  : Matches the end of the string

// Replacement:

    news/foobar.php?id=$1&artName=$2
news/foobar.php?                  : Path to file and start of query string (?)
                id=$1             : First query parameter ($1 is a call back to capture group 1)
                     &            : & goes between parameters in the query string     
                      artName=$2  : Second query parameter ($2 is a call back to capture group 2)


// Flags:

[NC,L,NE]
 NC       : Makes the match case insensitive
    L     : Stops the .htaccess from applying further rules
      NE  : Stops the rewrite escaping the & in the query string.
            Without it & would become %26
```

**Side Note**

Remember that, now, when navigating to pages you are using the url like:

```
example.com/news/foobar/21/Hello-World
<a href="example.com/news/foobar/21/Hello-World">Click me!!</a>
```

and in PHP you're still using `$_GET`:

```
echo $_GET["id"];       // 21
echo $_GET["artName"];  // Hello-World
```

Comment: I collect my articles from a database so I dont type the name adn id of the article, instead I have it as example.com/news/foobar/'.$row['id'].'/'.$row['linkAddress'].' does that mean that the condition will not work unless I write out the parameters instead of collecting them from the database?

Comment: Also I used your code for the Rewrite rule, I still get the same error. this is my new rule: RewriteRule ^news/foobar/(\d+)/([\w-]+)/?$ news/foobar.php?id=$1&artName=$2 [NC,L,NE]
but it is still unable to collect the get variables

Comment: @GhaithIshaq: Try putting `Options -MMultiViews` at top your htaccess

Comment: @GhaithIshaq no, that's not what it means -- it just means that you have to output the links in the _pretty_ style; but that seems to be what you're doing so that's okay. Can you show an example of a URL that's been output by the database? The rewrite rule only accepts numbers for the id and numbers, letters, underscore, and hyphen for the name (and there should be no spaces!)

Comment: @GhaithIshaq also you can try what @anubhava suggested (`Options -MultiViews` at the top of your `.htaccess` file) there's a chance your rewrite rule isn't working because the file `foobar` is being matched before hand!

Comment: @GhaithIshaq once you've done the above try putting `echo"<pre>";var_dump($_GET);exit;` at the VERY top of your `foobar.php` and accessing a _pretty_ URL see what content it comes up with. Also.. You said about an error? What actually is the error?

Comment: @Steven  when I put  Options -MultiViews my link becomes a 404 error and I put the variable dump you mentioned at the beginning of the page but it doesnt display anything after I take out the Options -MultiViews

Comment: @Steven when I said error i meant that page is still displaying but get variabes are not being collected, but for some reason after I place Options -MultiViews at top of .htaccess then visiting that page becomes a 404 error

Comment: @steven also when you mentioned that in my case we can skip the rewrite rules, did you mean I should take out RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d and
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f because there is no use for them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225430/discussion-between-steven-and-ghaith-ishaq).

Comment: My hosting company required me to have RewriteBase / for this to work, After I enabled it, your code worked perfectly, thank you for everything